# View router webpage via remote PC

Tags: ssh, routing, reverse-tunnel

Not sure if this can be done but here goes.

What I want to acheive is this, a user on a laptop can view a router web page that is on another PC (client), the route to this client is via another PC (Server).

So the connection is from Laptop to server to client, to add to the complication the client PC internet provider blocks all incomming requests so cannot use port forwarding on the clients router, to overcome this I use reverse ssh tunnel on the client to the server so the server browser can view the clients router web page - so far so good.

What I want to do now is connect the laptop to the server by another internet connection and forward the client's router web page to the laptop.

I have played around with NAT on the server but doesn't seem to do what I want.

Can this be done?

Paul.

Comment: This is possible but it depends on what the router allows as to if it can be done from within the router - typically WAN access or Remote Configuration are terms used associated with what you're after.

Comment: Ok, I used the router web page as an example. If you were on the Client PC and using the browser viewing a device that has a web interface for configuration etc. I simply want to be able to view that device local to the client PC on the laptop somewhere else on the planet. The client has 2 way communitation to our central server using xmlrpc and reverse ssh tunneling, the laptop logs onto the server to get some information from the client which is stored on the server. The bit I want to do is be able to view the device status web page in real time via the server.

Comment: BTW: If I sit at the server I can view the device web page that is on the client, this is via reverse ssh tunnel. Just want to move it one hop further on.  To add, I'm thinking that I may need to add another network card in the server so that I can use it as a gateway back to the client and maybe use NAT

Comment: So, is the question then, how can you get remote access to your server?

Comment: No - The laptop that is connected to the server via the internet and the browser on the laptop views the html web page that is on a device conected to the client. i.e. the same web page you would view if you were sitting at the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with SSH Port Forwarding.

This command will redirect any connection attempt at `$SERVER:10000` to `$DEVICE:80`.

```
client$ ssh -R 10000:$DEVICE:80 $SERVER
```

where `$SERVER` may as well be a local IP address.  `$DEVICE` may be any name or address identifying the device from the client's point of view.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  That certainly works :)  Now I would like to do the same thing without running/installing any programs such as ssh or changing the browser settings.  The ultimate aim is for any laptop user simply connects to our server and can view the status page.   I have acheived this by using 'PassPort_1_0_1' on the server to perform local port mapping, have tried using netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=90 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.1.200 instead but this doesn't work

Comment: _Now I would like to do the same thing without running/installing any programs such as ssh or changing the browser settings._ You mean on the laptops?  What about authorization?

Comment: Yes to the laptops.  The user logs on to the server and on the web page is a url that will point to the device status page, the idea is that any authorised user can view this on any internet device, such as iPad, Android and Windows etc. using thier default browser :)

Comment: Does the device have its own authorization mechanism? If not, I don't think plain packet mangling is going to help you.  I'd suggest a server side scripting solution.

Comment: By server side scripting solution I mean jsp, php, nodeJS and the like (See [phpproxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/) for example)

Comment: Most devices will have its own authorization mechanism, just think of it as a router admin page. Thanks for the idea of server side scripting, I will look in this :)

Comment: Then `client$ ssh -R 10000:localhost:80 $SERVER` will suffice and you can put the link `http://$SERVER:10000` on the server page

Comment: I think that would give you the web page on the client not the device on the client as the localhost port 10000 goes to the client on port 80

Comment: sry, should have written `client$ ssh -R 10000:$DEVICE:80 $SERVER`